# Why does my Django form not raise Validation Error?

Tags: django, forms

I read through most SO cases regarding this issue but all are kind of specific, so I come here for help.

I have impelemented a range filter in my Django project that takes in two inputs set to a low bound and high bound value, and displays the range of data within those bounds.

What I'm trying to do, is make it so when a user inputs a higher number in the low bound than the high bound value, a ValidationError is raised for the user to see on the front end, and results are not displayed. I am a bit new to working with Django forms, but I can supply my code, and maybe someone could provide a solution

**forms.py**

```
class PlayerForm(forms.Form):

# player forms
     points_high = forms.IntegerField(validators = [MinValueValidator(0)],
                            min_value=0, 
                            label = 'Reviews',
                            required = False,
                            widget = forms.NumberInput(
                                        attrs={'id': 'pointsHigh',
                                               'name': 'pointsHigh',
                                               'href': '#',
                                               'value': '',
                                               'class': "form-control"}))

     points_low = forms.IntegerField(validators = [MinValueValidator(0)], 
                                min_value=0, 
                                required = False,
                                widget = forms.NumberInput(
                                            attrs={'id': 'pointsLow',
                                                   'name': 'pointsLow',
                                                   'href': '#',
                                                   'value': '',
                                                   'class': "form-control"}))

     def check_bounds(self):
    """custom validation to check if low bound value is higher than high bound value"""
        data = self.cleaned_data
        player_low = data['player_low']
        player_high = data['player_high']

        if player_low and player_high:
            if player_low > player_high:
                raise forms.ValidationError(_("Low bound value cannot be higher than high bound value!"))
            
        return data
```

**views.py**

```
def player_points(request):

    players_form = PlayerForm()

    players_high = request.GET.get('players_high')
    players_low = request.GET.get('players_low')

    stat_kwargs = {points__lte: players_high,
                   points__gte: players_low}

    players = Players.objects.filter(**stat_kwargs)

    context = {
              'players': players
              'form': players_form
        }

 return render(request, 'nba/players.html', context)
```

Essentially, the goal is to take user input, check it in our `check_bounds` function, and return the Error if it doesn't work. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

The form will not call your function automatically. You will need to add in to your form a place to call your function. One place you could do this is you can override the form `clean()` function. Something like this:

```
def clean(self):
   cleaned_data = super().clean()
   self.check_bounds()
```

This will call your function when your django form would normally call the `clean()` function.

Also, I don't really understand the purpose of the line `return data` in your `check_bounds()` function. What is the reason you put that line in there?

Comment: Honestly, I just thought we had to return the data from this function. I'm honestly not sure why it's there. I'm essentially following other people's templates to execute this code. In implementing your method above, however, does everything look good? Like, in my ```check_bounds```, method? And, in the view, wouldn't I have to call the clean method, as well?

Comment: Unless you are going to do something with the data that would be returned from your function, you shouldn't need that return line. Other than that your function looks fine to me. You wouldn't have to call the `clean()` method in your view because the method is called automatically from the way that django forms function.

Comment: That makes sense.. can I ask what the point of the `cleaned_data = super().clean()` line? It's not being used. Also, I'm not getting a Validation error when the bounds are misaligned, as is expected, so something must be off here. Thanks for the response, though!

Comment: I guess I had that line in because of the tutorial I followed when I did that on my project a while ago. I'm not sure if it is super important or not to have in there. Maybe try putting the code of your `check_bounds` method into the overridden `clean` method and see if that works? Or can you tell me what values you are using in your range to test if the error is raised properly?

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't. I'll double check my logic.. but what I'm trying to understand is, in the clean function, how does my form know what value exists in `points_low` and `points_high`? Does that makes sense? Like, How does it read the input value? The input value is read in the views.py as far as I understand

Comment: Primarily, views are mainly for rendering things to the page using templates, and telling the page what kind of data to use. In your view, you are telling the page what form to use, but all the actual functionality for things like validation of data is done through the form. Also, are you sure that the error isn't being raised correctly? Looking at your view it doesn't look like you are checking if the form is valid anyways, you are just rendering the page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239714/discussion-between-nick-rinaldi-and-nathan-roberts).